# Android SDK preference in eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-juno

I use eclipse Juno, have purpose to build an android application. But i am now facing a problem. In Window > Preference > Android, i dont know which SDK location. Is there any links (for download SDK) exactly compatible with Eclipse Juno. I really need it.

Comment: can you please specify what exactly is your requirement... you want plugins for eclipse or do you want the android sdk

Comment: Google support for Eclipse as an Android development platform ends **this month**. If you are starting with Android development you should use Android Studio.